# Using a (Recursive?) CTE + Window Functions to zero out sales orders?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am trying to use a recursive CTE + window functions to find the last outcome of a series of buy/sell orders.

First, here's some nomenclature:

- field_id is the store's ID.
- Field_number is an order number, but can be reused by the same person
- Field_date is the date of the initial order.
- Field_inserted is when this specific transaction occcurred.
- Field_sale is whether we bought or returned it.

Unfortunately, because of the way the systems work, I do NOT get the cost when an item is returned, so figuring out the last outcome for an order is complicated (did we wind up selling any).  I need to match the purchase with the sale,  Which normally works pretty well.  However, there are cases such as below when it fails, and I'm trying to find a way to do this in one pass, possibly using a recursive CTE.

Here's some code.

```
DECLARE @tablea TABLE (field_id int, field_number CHAR(3), field_date datetime, field_inserted DATETIME, field_sale varchar(4))
INSERT INTO @tablea
VALUES 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:00:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:01', 'buy'),
(2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'REtu'),
(1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');
```

Now to remove the buys that were then returned.  The ISNULL is because I'm the NOT IN will ignore all the rows that have NULL for the _lead/_lag values.

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS row_num,
        field_id,
        field_number, 
        field_date,
        field_sale,
       lead(field_sale) OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lead,      
       lag(field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lag    
FROM   @tablea
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Buy'  AND ISNULL(field_sale_lead,'') = 'Retu')--AND field_sale_lead IS NOT null)
  AND NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Retu' AND ISNULL(field_sale_lag,'') =  'buy' )--AND field_sale_lag  IS NOT NULL)
```

And I felt pretty smug and thought I had it.  However, that's the simple case.  Buy, Return, Buy, Return.  Let's try another case, Buy Buy Return Return, which is still valid, but obviously would result in a net of 0..

```
DECLARE @tablea TABLE (field_id int, field_number CHAR(3), field_date datetime, field_inserted DATETIME, field_sale varchar(4))
INSERT INTO @tablea
VALUES 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:00:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Retu'),
(2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');


WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS row_num,
        field_id,
        field_number, 
        field_date,
        field_sale,
       lead(field_sale) OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lead,      
       lag(field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lag    
FROM   @tablea
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Buy'  AND ISNULL(field_sale_lead,'') = 'sell')--AND field_sale_lead IS NOT null)
  AND NOT (cte.field_sale = 'sell' AND ISNULL(field_sale_lag,'') =  'buy' )--AND field_sale_lag  IS NOT NULL)
```

When you do this, though, you realize that it found direct matches, but now there's still a Buy/Return pair, and I'd like to cancel that out.

It's at this point I'm stuck.  I've done Recursive CTEs before, but for whatever reason I can't figure out how to recurse and make it cancel out 1/1/100 and 4/1/100.  All I've managed to do is have it choke on the recursion.

```
DECLARE @tablea TABLE (field_id int, field_number CHAR(3), field_date datetime, field_inserted DATETIME, field_sale varchar(4))
INSERT INTO @tablea
VALUES 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:00:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Retu'),
(2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');

WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS row_num,
        field_id,
        field_number, 
        field_date,
        field_sale,
        field_inserted,
       lead(field_sale) OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lead,      
       lag(field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number, field_date ORDER BY field_inserted) AS field_sale_lag    
FROM   @tablea
--) 
--SELECT * FROM cte
--WHERE NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Buy'  AND ISNULL(field_sale_lead,'') = 'Retu')--AND field_sale_lead IS NOT null)
--AND NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Retu' AND ISNULL(field_sale_lag,'') =  'buy' )--AND field_sale_lag  IS NOT NULL)

UNION ALL
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  cte.field_id, cte.field_number, cte.field_date ORDER BY cte.field_inserted) AS row_num,
        cte.field_id,
        cte.field_number, 
        cte.field_date,
        cte.field_sale,
        cte.field_inserted,
       lead(cte.field_sale) OVER (PARTITION BY cte.field_id, cte.field_number, cte.field_date ORDER BY cte.field_inserted) AS field_sale_lead,      
       lag(cte.field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY cte.field_id, cte.field_number, cte.field_date ORDER BY cte.field_inserted) AS field_sale_lag    
FROM   @tablea INNER JOIN cte ON cte.field_date = [@tablea].field_date AND cte.field_id = [@tablea].field_id AND cte.field_number = [@tablea].field_number
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Buy'  AND ISNULL(field_sale_lead,'') = 'Retu')--AND field_sale_lead IS NOT null)
  AND NOT (cte.field_sale = 'Retu' AND ISNULL(field_sale_lag,'') =  'buy' )--AND field_sale_lag  IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: What if the sequence is (Buy Buy Buy Return Return),which Buys must be removed?

Comment: @serg good question. I would think it would be the last two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can tackle this **without loops or recursion** by using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** like so:

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to remove sales that have been returned
, and for each `'retu'` it should remove the most recent `'buy'`.

First we will add `id` using `row_number()` to our rowset so we can uniquely identify our rows.

Next, we add `br_rn` (short for Buy/Return RowNumber) partitioned by `field_id, field_number, field_date`, but we will **also add** `field_sale` to the partition; and we will order it by `field_inserted desc`. 
This will let us match each `'retu'` with the most recent `'buy'`, and once we can do that, we can eliminate all of the pairs with `not exists()`:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      id = row_number() over (
        order by field_id, field_number, field_date, field_inserted asc
        ) 
    , field_id
    , field_number
    , field_date 
    , field_inserted 
    , field_sale
    , br_rn = row_number() over (
        partition by field_id, field_number, field_date, field_sale
        order by field_inserted desc
        ) 
  from @tablea
)
select 
    id 
  , field_number
  , field_date
  , field_inserted
  , field_sale
from cte
where not exists (
  select 1
  from cte as i
  where i.field_id = cte.field_id
    and i.field_number = cte.field_number
    and i.field_date = cte.field_date
    and i.br_rn = cte.br_rn
    and i.id <> cte.id
    )
order by id
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TKXOC61533

For this input:

```
  (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:00:00', 'Buy') 
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Retu')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Retu')
, (2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');
```

returns:

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | field_id | field_number | field_date |   field_inserted    | field_sale |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  5 |        1 |          110 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
|  6 |        2 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

and for this input:

```
  (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy') 
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:04:00', 'Retu')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:05:00', 'Buy') 
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:06:00', 'Retu')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:07:00', 'Retu')
, (2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');
```

returns:

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | field_id | field_number | field_date |   field_inserted    | field_sale |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:01:00 | Buy        |
|  8 |        1 |          110 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
|  9 |        2 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

for this input:

```
  (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:04:00', 'Retu')
, (1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:05:00', 'Retu')
, (1, 100, '20170312','20170311 01:06:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 100, '20170312','20170311 01:07:00', 'Buy')
, (2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy')
, (1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy')
```

returns:

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | field_id | field_number | field_date |   field_inserted    | field_sale |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  5 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-11 01:06:00 | Buy        |
|  6 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-11 01:07:00 | Buy        |
|  7 |        1 |          110 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
|  8 |        2 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

---

It may help illustrate what we are doing to take a look what the cte is returning before we eliminate any pairs.

Looking at just the set that needs filtering, before we filter it:

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-------+
| id | field_id | field_number | field_date |   field_inserted    | field_sale | br_rn |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:01:00 | Buy        |     4 |
|  2 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:02:00 | Buy        |     3 |
|  3 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:03:00 | Buy        |     2 |
|  4 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:04:00 | Retu       |     3 |
|  5 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:05:00 | Buy        |     1 |
|  6 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:06:00 | Retu       |     2 |
|  7 |        1 |          100 | 2017-03-11 | 2017-03-11 01:07:00 | Retu       |     1 |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-------+
```

Looking at it like this, we can easily see that the `'buy'` order `id` `1` has a `br_rn` of `4` and there is no associated `'retu'`.

Comment: I found an odd case where it doesn't work. Writing up details now.

Comment: unsure why this set doesn't work right. I'd expect it to give the buys on 1/100/20170312, but only the last two show. Rereading the explanation now. `(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:04:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:05:00', 'Retu'), 
(1, 100, '20170312','20170311 01:06:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170312','20170311 01:07:00', 'Buy'),
(2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy')`

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account `field_inserted` of the paired buy/return. My guess is a return must be paired with a buy which precedes it according to `field_inserted`, as you can not return what was not bought yet.

Comment: @mbourgon I have updated the answer to correct my oversight. I initially failed to include `and i.field_date = cte.field_date` in the `not exists()` even though it is in the `partition by`. I have also updated the rextester demo with your additional data set and included the results in the answer.

Comment: Makes sense, and that fixes the problem!  If you go to NTSSUG or the DFW SQLSat, let me know and I'll buy you a drink or something at the next after-party!

Answer (score 0):

One thing i can suggest delete pairs of sequential buy/return while it's possible. Try

```
DECLARE @tablea TABLE (field_id int, field_number CHAR(3), field_date datetime, field_inserted DATETIME, field_sale varchar(4))
INSERT INTO @tablea
VALUES 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:01:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:02:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:04:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:05:00', 'Buy'), 
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:06:00', 'Retu'),
(1, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:07:00', 'Retu'),
(2, 100, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy'),
(1, 110, '20170311','20170311 01:03:00', 'Buy');

select * from @tablea
order by field_id,
        field_number, 
        field_inserted 

declare @eoj int =1;
while @eoj > 0
begin
    WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            case field_sale when 'Buy' then 
                  lead (field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number  ORDER BY field_inserted)
                  when 'Retu' then 
                  lag (field_sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY field_id, field_number  ORDER BY field_inserted)
                  end nbr_type,
            field_id,
            field_number, 
            field_date,
            field_sale,
            field_inserted 
    FROM   @tablea 
    ) 
    delete  
    from cte 
    where nbr_type is not null and nbr_type <> field_sale;
    set @eoj = @@rowcount;
    -- check it
    select * from @tablea
    order by field_id,
            field_number, 
            field_inserted; 
end;
```

It will be repeated N+1 times where N is the length of the longest sequence of returns. N=2 in the above example.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't considered doing it deletes to get that way.  Thanks for looking at it.